# Remove selected row from data grid

Tags: c#, uwp, datagrid

How can I add an option to remove selected row from `DataGrid`?

```
<controls:DataGrid
   x:Name="targetsDataGrid"
   ItemsSource="{x:Bind Source}"
   AutoGenerateColumns="False"
   ColumnWidth="*"
   Height="220"
   Margin="0,40,0,0"
   VerticalAlignment="Top"
   HorizontalContentAlignment="Center"
   CanUserResizeColumns="False"
   CanUserSortColumns="False"
   HeadersVisibility="All"
   GridLinesVisibility="Horizontal">
   <controls:DataGrid.Columns>
       <controls:DataGridTextColumn Header="X" Binding="{Binding X}"/>
       <controls:DataGridTextColumn Header="Y" Binding="{Binding Y}"/>
       <controls:DataGridTextColumn Header="Z" Binding="{Binding Z}"/>
       <controls:DataGridTextColumn Header="W" Binding="{Binding W}"/>
   </controls:DataGrid.Columns>
</controls:DataGrid>
```

I prefer to do it with an external button.

Answer (score 1):

I see you are using data binding, which means the items are in fact stored in a `Source` collection. You can use `SelectedItem` to create a two-way binding to another property which will store the selected item:

```
public YourItemType Selected { get; set; }
```

And XAML:

```
<controls:DataGrid
   x:Name="targetsDataGrid"
   ItemsSource="{x:Bind Source}"
   SelectedItem="{x:Bind Selected, Mode=TwoWay}" ...
```

Now add a button and in its `Click` event handler or `Command` do:

```
if (Selected != null)
{
   Source.Remove(Selected);
}
```

Make sure `Source` is a `ObservableCollection<YourItemType>` to make sure the `DataGrid` can observe changes in the collection and update the UI accordingly.